# A better syntax for switch-like conditions in Django Template

Tags: django, django-templates

Does anyone know a less bulky way of performing a switch-like evaluation in Django Template than the one below?

```
<div class="alert {% if message.level == DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS.ERROR %}alert-danger
                  {% elif message.level == DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS.WARNING %}alert-warning
                  {% elif message.level == DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS.SUCCESS %}alert-success
                  {% elif message.level == DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS.INFO %}alert-info
                  {% elif message.level == DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS.DEBUG %}alert-dark
                  {% else %}alert-light{% endif %} alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
  {{ message }}
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags) and pass the `level` as an argument. Something like this

```py
# yourapp/templatetags/message_level.py

from django import template
# import your DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_message_css_level(level):
    '''Returns the class name for a tag based on the message level'''
    if level == DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS.ERROR:
        return 'danger'
    elif level == DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS.WARNING:
        return 'warning'
    elif level == DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS.SUCCESS:
        return 'success'
    elif level == DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS.INFO:
        return 'info'
    elif level == DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS.DEBUG:
        return 'dark'
    else:
        return 'light'
```

Also create an empty `__init__.py` file inside the `templatetags`, this is important. Then in your `template` add you new custom template tag:

```html
{% load message_level %}
<div class="alert alert-{% get_message_css_level message.level %} alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
  {{ message }}
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>
```